# how i print vowels and what they are?

Tags: java

Everytime i input my sentence it prints out the outcome each time it goes through the loop. i assume i have to put the printlines outside the loop?

```
import java.util.*;
public class homework4{
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Scanner
Scanner keyBd = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a sentence ");
String userIn = keyBd.nextLine();
  int count = 0;
  String empty= "";

  //Code
    for (int i = 0; i < userIn.length(); i++) {
           char ch = userIn.charAt(i);

        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U') {
            count++;

                     System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in this string");

    }        
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U') {
            count++;
            empty += ch + " ";

                     System.out.println("The vowels are: " + empty);

    }
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you do. And there's no reason to repeat the `if` and increment `count` again.

Comment: Yes, and did you try it?  Please do your research before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
public class homework4{
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Scanner
Scanner keyBd = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a sentence ");
String userIn = keyBd.nextLine();
int count = 0;
String empty= "";

//Code
for (int i = 0; i < userIn.length(); i++) {
       char ch = userIn.charAt(i);

    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U') {
        count++;
        empty += ch + " ";                    
}
}
System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in this string");
System.out.println("The vowels are: " + empty);
}
}
```

No need to check condition two times. As you are updating variables (`count` & `empty`) in loop, have to print only once after exiting from loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test for vowels twice? (and add to `count` twice), only once:-

```
 if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U'){
    count++;
    empty += ch + " ";
 }
```

And your print statement doesn't need to happen every time you find a vowel:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < userIn.length(); i++) {
 // not in here
}
System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in this string\n" + "The vowels are: " + empty);
```

**Additionally...**

If statements are ugly here, where there are many conditions.  A switch would be easier to read and more efficient:-

```
 switch (ch){
   case 'a': case 'A':
   case 'e': case 'E':
   case 'i': case 'I':
   case 'o': case 'O':
   case 'u': case 'U':
     count++;
     empty += ch + " ";
     break;
 }
```

Or move the whole condition into a method

```
public boolean isVowel(char c){
  return (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U');
}
```

and use

```
if (isVowel(ch)){
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to move the print statement outside and put a check condition if the count is still zero then it means there were no vowels and if count is not zero you can print it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class homework4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Scanner
    Scanner keyBd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence ");
    String userIn = keyBd.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    String empty = "";
    //Code
    for (int i = 0; i < userIn.length(); i++) {
        char ch = userIn.charAt(i);

        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U') {
            count++;
            empty += ch + " ";

        }
    }

    if(count == 0){
        System.out.println("There are no vowels in the input string");
    }else {
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in this string");
        System.out.println("The vowels are: " + empty);
    }


}
```

}